# Access Control Origin issue when trying to do $http.post to IFTTT in Ionic & Angular

Tags: angularjs, post, ionic-framework, http-post, ifttt

I am having an issue while trying to perform a $http.post to the IFTTT maker channel. Below is the code I am using to perform the POST:

```
$http.post(
    'https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{my-event}/with/key/{my-key}',
    {value1:"hello",value2:"goodbye"}
).then(
     function successCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
     }, 
     function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log("error: ",response);
     });
```

The response I get is the following:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://maker.ifttt.com/trigger/{my-event}/with/key/{my-key}. 
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I have the cordova-whitelist plugin and have tried various solutions adding `Access-Control-Origin` to the header and still get a similar response.

Comment: is this a browser error?

Comment: I don't believe so. I've tried it on several browsers and on several machines. Still the same error.

Comment: there is a workaround using CORS plugin https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: This functionally works for me, but not for a product used by others. I need a stable way to do this.

Comment: cordova-whitelist plugin is not for browser. Only to execute in an app on a device.

Comment: Well, Cross Origin only exists on browsers (or, a localhost). You won't get a CORS error on a device. So why not just use the chrome or mozilla extension?
I haven't checked or used this, but if you want to, you can check this on ionic blog
http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Comment: You are correct @Marko, Once I built it and deployed it to the device, it worked perfectly. If you'd like, make your comment an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: I've actually seen this question a lot these days, so I might as well post an answer here instead of commenting everyone lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CORS issues only exist on browsers. In this case, they only exist using `ionic serve`.

When deploying an app to an actual **device**, you will **not** get a CORS error.

> Since CORS is only an issue when running your app in development mode
>   with ionic serve, and not when running as a mobile app packaged with
>   Cordova, a simpler option is to just disable CORS altogether for local
>   development. For Chrome for example there's a plugin called
>   "Allow-Control-Allow-Origin: *" that lets you disable CORS.

If you still want to handle cors in a code way, you can get more info about that here http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/

Having that in mind, it's a faster and a better way to just get a CORS plugin for mozilla or chrome. You can get them here

Chrome - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Mozilla - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/